# Tony Romo broadcast times?

Tags: nfl, media

How can I check if Tony Romo is commentating a particular CBS game? I know he usually commentates the afternoon games, but which ones? The CBS site doesn't seem to list the commentators for each game, or am I missing something?

Comment: he's a gem.  such a delight to watch one of his games,

Answer (score 1):

506sports.com is generally the big name for NFL broadcast maps. They're most known for finding out what your US local TV station is airing, but their maps also shows who they think the scheduled announcers are.